# Display Phone Number or link based on Geolocation?

Tags: hyperlink, geolocation, location, phone-number, geotargetting

Does anyone know how to have a phone number & link to appear based on the visitors Geolocation or IP address? For instance, lets say I have 5 locations across 2 different states. I want to have the phone number in the header to show the phone number of the location that is closest to the person who is visiting the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull some info from geolocation of the IP address. E.g. http://whois.arin.net/ui/

You can also ask the user's browser for their location: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/

You would need to extend the above method using browser detection to include other browsers than just Chrome.